# Replacing a value in xml file using awk or sed

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, sh

I'd like to replace the value of `"ThreadGroup.num_threads"` which is `2000` with another value i.e. `500`. My file name is *"test.xml"*

here is the xml file that i want to replace `2000` value with `500`:

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="JWT-API Thread Group" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
    <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp> </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2000</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
</ThreadGroup>
```

I have made a script that helps to replace the value but somehow i am hard-coding the values as well as hardcoded the path location. I need a way so that it recognizes the location itself just as i defined in awk command and replaces the value using parameter as defined `$Ratio`

```
#!/bin/bash
Ratio="500"
for file in Sample.jmx; do
        awk -F"[<>]" '/ThreadGroup.num_threads/{print $3}' $file > output.json
        sed -i 's:<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2000</stringProp>:<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">500</stringProp>:' $file
done
Output=$((`cat < output.json`))
echo $Output
#UpScale = number_of_threads / 1000
UpScale=$((`cat < output.json` / $Ratio))
echo $UpScale
```

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: So replace `<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2000</stringProp>` with `<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">500</stringProp>`.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Whats the question? where is your code? this isnt a code writing service. People will be willing to help if you show you have made some attempt.

Comment: I have edited the post and put my work done but somehow i want to rid off all hard-coded stuff that i worked

Comment: you can create string using  `'s:..text...'$Ratio'...text..:'`

Comment: you could event create this string before `for`-loop - `text='s:..text...'$Ratio'...text..:'` and later use `sed -i $text $file`

Comment: you could also search shorter text `s:ThreadGroup.num_threads">2000<:ThreadGroup.num_threads">'$Ratio'<:'` or maybe even shorter if there is no other `num_threads` - `'s:num_threads">2000<:num_threads">'$Ratio'<:'`

Comment: @furas .. it would be helpful if you can write in a code the way you explain so that i can take as reference

Comment: Thanks Furas..it actually worked. but getting this error :```+ sed -i 's:<stringProp' 'name="num_threads">2000</stringProp>:<stringProp' 'name="num_threads">500</stringProp>:' Sample.jmx
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command ```

Comment: I see spaces between `' '` so it treats strings as separated arguments (first: `'s:<stringProp'`, second: `'name="num_threads">2000</stringProp>:<stringProp'`, third:  `'name="num_threads">500</stringProp>:'`) and it doesn't concatenate them in one string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put variable between strings

```
's:..text...'$Ratio'...text..:'
```

and it will concatenate all in one string - but there can't be spaces between strings and `$Ratio`

```
sed -i 's:<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2000</stringProp>:<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">'$Ratio'</stringProp>:' $file
```

It there is no other `num_threads` then you could use shorter strings

```
sed -i 's:num_threads">2000<:num_threads">'$Ratio'<:' $file
```

Using `()` (or `\( \)` on some systems) you can catch text in input string and use it in output string as `$1`, `$2`

```
sed -i 's:(num_threads">)2000(<):$1'$Ratio'$2:' $file
```

This way you can create shorter string even for longer version

```
sed -i 's:(<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">)2000(</stringProp>):$1'$Ratio'$2:' $file
```

---

On Linux Mint I have to use `\( \)` instead of `()`,

```
sed -i 's:\(num_threads">\)2000\(<\):$1'$Ratio'$2:' $file
```

or I have to add option `-E` or `--regexp-extended`

```
sed -i -E 's:(num_threads">)2000(<):$1'$Ratio'$2:' $file
```

Comment: Genius !! BIG THANKS !